# working of extern keyword

Tags: c, gcc

I have defined a variable in one file and declared it in another file using the extern keyword. but i have declared it with different datatype..

```
file1.c  
    char i;
    main()  
    {   
        foo();  
    }
```

file2.c

```
void foo()  
{  
    extern int i;  
    i = 130;  
    printf("%d", i);  
}
```

In the above program, memory is allocated for 'i' in the main function as char datatype.
And the answer after executing should be negative(-127). But it prints 130. Whatever the value assigned to 'i' in the foo() function is printed not only 130.

Comment: Probably `extern` has no meaning for local variables inside a function.

Comment: You've not provided a definition of `i`; the one in `main()` is a local variable, not one that might be visible  in `foo()`.

Comment: the case you have given will give you error.. make `i` global

Comment: you taged `gcc` but this code produce `undefined reference to `i'` to mysystem.

Comment: @Celada: No. `extern` in a local declaration has a very sigificant meaning. It turns a local declaration into a declaration that refers to a global variable.

Comment: @srikanth reddy: The code you posted so far will not compile (i.e. it won't link due to missing definition of global `int i`).

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for that correction. So my followup question would be, in that case, how can the code possibly link? And then your following comment answers that question too :-)

Comment: @Celada: This code cannot and will not link. The OP is either posting inaccurate code or hiding some parts of the code from us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Analysis — What is wrong with the code

In your code:

#### file1.c

```
int main(void)  
{  
    char i;   // Warning: unused variable
    foo();  
}
```

#### file2.c

```
void foo(void)  
{  
    extern int i;  
    i = 130;  
    printf("%d", i);  
}
```

The variable `i` in `main()` is wholly unrelated to the `i` referred to in `foo()`.  The variable `i` in `main()` is strictly local to `main()` and is not passed to `foo()`; `foo()` is unable to see that `i`.

On Mac OS X 10.7.5 with GCC 4.7.1, the files compile separately, but they can't be linked because there is no definition for variable `i`.

If we move the variable `i` outside of `main()`, then the program links:

#### file2.h

```
extern void foo(void);
```

#### file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.h"

char i = 'A';

int main(void)
{
    printf("i = %d (%c)\n", i, i);
    foo();
    printf("i = %d (%c)\n", i, i);
    return(0);
}
```

#### file2.c

```
#include "file2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    extern int i;
    i = 130;
    printf("i = %d (%c)\n", i, i);
}
```

This now links and runs, but it invokes undefined behaviour.  The linker does not notice that the size of `i` should be `sizeof(int)` but is `sizeof(char)`. The assignment in `foo()`, though, goes trampling out of bounds of the `i` that is allocated.  It doesn't cause visible damage in this program, but that's pure luck.

When I run it on a little-endian machine (Intel x86/64), the output is:

```
i = 65 (A)
i = 130 (?)
i = -126 (?)
```

When I ran it on a big-endian machine (SPARC), I got a different result (which isn't very surprising; the behaviour is undefined, so any result is valid):

```
i = 65 (A)
i = 130 (?)
i = 0 ()
```

The most significant byte of the 4-byte integer was written over the only byte of the 1-byte character, hence the zero in the third line out output.  Note too that it was lucky that the character was allocated an address that was a multiple of 4 bytes; that was not guaranteed and a misaligned address for an `int` would have caused a bus error (though experimentation suggests that it doesn't happen on SPARC even when `i` is forced onto an odd address; I'm not sure what is happening).

### Synthesis — Correct Handling of `extern`

The correct way to handle this is to avoid writing external variable declarations such as `extern int i;` in any source file; such declarations should only appear in a header that is used everywhere the variable needs to be used.

#### file2.h

```
extern char i;
extern void foo(void);
```

With that change in place (and the corresponding `extern int i;` removed), then the output is self-consistent:

```
i = 65 (A)
i = -126 (?)
i = -126 (?)
```

Note the role of the header in keeping both `file1.c` and `file2.c` in line with each other.  It ensures that the definition in `file1.c` matches the declaration in `file2.h`, and the use of `file2.h` in `file2.c` ensures that the declaration used there is correct, too.  See also [What are `extern` variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c).

Answer (score 6):

*"I have defined a variable in one file and declared it in another file using the extern keyword"*. That is just not true. `char i` and in `main` is not in any way related to `int i` in `foo`.

The variable you define as `char i` inside `main` has no linkage. It cannot be referred to by name from anywhere else in the program besides that `main` function. There's simply no way to do it in C. It is a local variable.

Your `extern int i;` declaration inside `foo` has absolutely no relation to that local `char i;` variable from `main`. It declares a completely different, independent variable `i`. The `extern int i` declaration in `foo` refers to a variable `i` with external linkage, i.e to a *global* variable `i`. You are still required to *define* that `i` somewhere. That `i` will have to be defined at file scope (since this is the only way to *define* a variable with external linkage). If you don't define it your program will not compile.

Entities with external linkage and entities with no linkage live in completely separate worlds. They know nothing about each other and never interact or interfere with each other.

As I said above, the code you posted in your question simply won't compile. The linker will tell you that you forgot to define the `int i` variable with external linkage that which you declared in used in `foo`. Yet, your post suggests that the code compiled successfully. This would simply mean that the code you posted is either inaccurate or incomplete. If the code is accurate, then somewhere else in your code you also defined a global variable `int i`. This is the global variable your `foo` works with, while the `char i` in `main` has absolutely nothing to do with anything.

---

What you have now, after your edit, is an invalid program again, albeit for a different reason. You defined a global variable `char i` in `file1.c` and then you attempted to link to it in `file2.c`. However, in `file2.c` you lied to the compiler by telling it that the global variable `i` has type `int`, while in reality it has type `char`.

The behavior of such program is undefined. It is illegal to use inconsistent types when declaring an entity with external linkage. If you declared a global variable of type `char` in one translation unit, you are not allowed to declare the same global variable with any other type in other translation units.

Some compilers might catch your error and refuse to compile the program. Most C compilers will not catch this error though. Instead the will produce a program that causes undefined behavior. This is what you got in your case. In your case that undefined behavior happened to manifest itself by printing `130` after you assigned `130` to your variable. Why you suddenly find it strange I don't know. Why you expect it to print `-127` I don't know either.

Comment: i forgot to define the 'i' as global above.. but i have defined it as global in my program while compiling..  but the answer is still the same..

Answer (score 1):

The `extern` declaration inside foo has absolutely no relation to that local char variable.

As far as I know, `extern` can be put in front of a variable declaration.
Perhaps this is a bit more confusing.
Doing that tells the compiler you want to share the variable between different `.c` files.
However, there has to be one `.c` file where the variable is declared without the `extern` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You're example wouldn't work anyway, as `extern` has no effect on local variables.

`extern` is a way to tell the compiler some variable you are using is implemented in another object file that you promise that you will link at link time. It is often used in library header files that involve global variables to tell the compiler that the variable is actually implemented in the library file.

Ex:
file1.c:

```
int thing;
int bork(int val) {
  return thing += val
}
```

file2.c

```
extern int thing
int main() {
  thing + 2;
}
```

Comment: Ditch the `extern "C"` part - question is tagged C, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when `i` is declared in one file as `global variable` then only it has external linkage.

Linker only looks for the symbol `i` which will be resolved at link time ,but types are not resolved by linker so I think it's `Undefined Behavior` when `i` is of different type and defind as global variable in one file and extern declaration is done in other file.

Answer (score -1):

In file1.c, `i` is defined (and declared implicitly) globally.

```
char i;
main()  
{    
    foo();  
}
```

file2.c extern is used with a variable `i`, it’s only declared not defined.

```
extern char i; 
void foo()  
{  
   printf("%d", i);  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are LYING to the compiler about the size of `i`. The compiler goes by what you have told it in foo, so you are getting the integer representation. Unfortunately, it won't really work reliably, because you have also written three bytes beyond your `char i;`

If you add `char j = 11;` and then print `j` in main after you call `foo();`, you'll notice that j is not 11 any more.

Lying to compilers is a bad idea. You get found out sooner or later!